# Django Restframework _ object level permission owner booleanfield

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I made this custom Permission class that owner is related to django user model.and user model related to UserProfile model with **related_name = "user_profile"** in UserProfile model I have a BooleanField default is false.

```
ad_ac = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Im trying to write a custom permission class that tells if the request.user has **ad_ac** field True .can create or update from request.
this is how get so far :

```
class OwnerAdPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    ''' object lvl permission for Ad owner '''
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.user.user_profile.ad_ac == True:
            return True
            return obj.owner == request.user
```

Answer (score 2):

after digging into stackoverflow I found my problem.
the problem was so obvious i didnt define **has_permission** in my custom permission.so has_object_permission only works we have created object.for Creating new object we have to define **has_permission**.

```
class OwnerAdPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    ''' object lvl permission for Ad owner '''
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.user_profile.ad_ac == True:
            return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

so i chanded the **has_permission** to my own usage.